# How to change the BarButtonItem back color?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress, toolbar

I am currently working in the C# windows application with DevExpress controls.
Now I want to change back color of bar button item while loading the form.
I've tried following code:

```
barButton.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

but the bar button back color not changed to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, bars use the [skins](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2534) to draw their content. In this case, all background colors are provided by specific skin elements, which cannot be changed. The only way to change a specific item's background color is to disable skins:
 put the `BarAndDockingController` component onto a form, and assign it to the `BarManager.Controller` property. Set `BarAndDockingController.PaintStyleName` or `LookAndFeel` to any non-skin style(for example "Flat"). Then use the `Bar.Appearance.BackColor` property to set the desired color.

Alternatively, you can create your own custom barItem in a way similar to the one described in the [How to change the background color of highlighted links](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A488.aspx) KB article.

Comment: @Vinoth: You are always welcome. But [you should always accept answer if the answer is right, and vote instead of thanks](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)))

Comment: Why does DevExpress make the styling and appearance of their controls so difficult. I get the idea of skins, or themes, which allow the user to apply a uniform look across the app. Similar to the power of CSS. However, any time I need to do some styling to devexpress controls it's an abysmal process. You want a button with just an image, no borders? Had to dig around for that one. There should be a way to override basic properties like bg color without some convoluted process. I shouldnt have to do this for a simple checkbox.